# deploy symfony server vps in cloud - Ubuntu 16

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, ubuntu, apache2

I use Apache2, Symfony 2 and PHP 7.1.

Deploy Symfony in VPS with a static IP (example 46.101.130.241:8000), no domain.

Here my config of the virtual directory:

[image]

.htaccess the project root:

[image]

Run project:

```
$ sudo php app/console server:start 46.101.130.241
```

Result:

```
No se puede acceder a este sitio

46.101.130.241 tardó demasiado en responder.
Buscar 101 130 241 8000 en Google
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @fileceru, Welcome to SO, please do not paste images of your files, instead paste the actual code, that will make your question to be more likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

The built in web server, the one you started with `sudo php app/console server:start 46.101.130.241` should not be used in production!!

If you want to try it out, you do not need Apache in front of it.

The recommended setup for Apache can be found in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) and it requires that you have mod_php or mod_proxy_fcgi with PHP-FPM installed and configured.

Comment: Could be more explicit please. I already used that configuration.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are missing without providing more information. Like, is you Apache running and listening on port 80? Did you try accessing the site with a browser? Does it return static files from the webroot? Can it serve a simple PHP script so you know that PHP is working correctly? What are you seeing in the error logs? etc.

It looks to me that you are lacking some sysadmin skills that would help you get to where you want to go. My advice is to ask somebody with more knowledge to set it up for you.

Comment: php runnig with project natives. Used el port 80.